# Fitting the same models in nlme and lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

The data are from [here](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~lang/Stat527a/aids.dat2)

```
library(nlme)
dat0 <- read.table("aids.dat2",head=T)
dat1 <- dat0[dat0$day<=90, ]   # use only first 90-day data
dat2 <- dat1[!apply(is.na(dat1),1,any),]  # remove missing data 

# Next, let's treat the data as longitudinal (or grouped) data 
aids.dat <- groupedData(lgcopy ~ day | patid, data=dat2)

# A NLME model fit, with random effects on all 4 parameters 
start <- c(10,0.5,6,0.005)  # starting value 

aids.dat$log10copy = log10(aids.dat$lgcopy)

nlme.fit <- nlme(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1),
                 fixed = list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1),
                 random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1))),
                 data =aids.dat, start=c(start)) 
summary(nlme.fit)
```

Here I fit a nonlinear mixed effects model using `nlme` in the `nlme` package. The model has 4 fixed effects and 4 random effects. I specified a diagonal structure on the variance-covariance matrix, and each `patid` forms a group.

```
library(lme4)
deriv_mod <- deriv( ~ exp(p1 - b1*t) + exp(p2 - b2*t + 1), 
                    c("p1", "b1", "p2", "b2"), function(t, p1, b1, p2, b2){})
nlmer.fit <- nlmer(deriv_mod ~ list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1) + 
                     list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1), data = aids.dat, start = c(start))
```

Here, I would like to fit the same model using the `lme4` package. From the documentation it seems that the `formula` for `nlmer` must also have a gradient component, thus I used the `deriv` function first. However, I am not sure how to specify the rest of the parameters? The

```
deriv_mod ~ list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1) + 
                     list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1)
```

is to specify 4 fixed effects (in the first list object) and their corresponding 4 random effects (in the second list object). However, I am not quite sure how to specify a diagonal variance-covariance structure and make sure that the observations are grouped by `patid`, like I had specified in `random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1)))` with `nlme`.

Comment: `lme4` doesn't allow you as much flexibility with the variance-covariance structure as `nlme`... are your RE's cross-classified, nested, etc? Can you give more details, please?

Comment: The REs are neither cross-classified nor nested. They are assumed to be independent from one another since I specified a diagonal structure on the variance covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to specify fixed effects `FE1 ... FE4` and independent random effects `RE1 ... RE4` is shown below

```
mod_fit <- lme4::nlmer(Y ~ FE1 + FE2 + FE3 + FE4 + 
  (1|RE1) + (1|RE2) + (1|RE3) + (1|RE4), data= dat)
```

The `nlme` package has slightly different syntax than `lme4` package.

```
mod_fit <- nlme::nlme(Y ~ FE1 + FE2 + FE3 + FE4 + 
      (1|RE1) + (1|RE2) + (1|RE3) + (1|RE4), 
  fixed= FE1 + FE2 + FE3 + FE4 ~ Y,
  groups= 1 ~ RE1 + RE2 + RE3 + RE4,
  data= dat)
```

That said, I'm not sure I completely understand the nuances of your question, so it's possible your situation means this needs to be slighly modified. If you provide comments, I'm happy to revise my answer as needed

Comment: I would like to fit the same exact model using `nlme` and `nlmer` (i.e. I'd like to see similar if not the same parameter estimates, SEs, etc) from both outputs. I was able to fit the model in `nlme` but not in `nlmer`.

Comment: @Adrian updating answer now

Comment: `lme4.fit <- lme4::nlmer(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1) + 
                         (1|p1) + (1|b1) + (1|p2) + (1|b2), data= aids.dat)` I tried this but it says `log10copy` is not found? But the variable does exist in my data.frame?

Comment: Please run my first chunk of code in my original post... it defines `log10copy` as a variable. This is a reproducible example unless I missed something......

Comment: @Adrian Thanks! You're getting an inaccurate error message. The problem appears to be with passing `deriv_mod` into the call stack. specifically, `nlformula` is not able to parse your model specification. It's not quite clear to me what your intent is; but you can try specifying the model more direclty in `nlmer`